# How to make background image use div inline with h1

Tags: css, background

I stack to create background image that located right of h1.

HTML

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h1>
        <div class="img2"></div> 
        IMAGE INLINE 
        <div class="img1"></div>
        <div class="img2"></div>
      </h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS

```
.img1{
  background: url('http://www.sample.com/img1.png') left center no-repeat;
  width:23px;
  height:24px;
  position:relative;
}
.img2{
  background: url('http://www.sample.com/img2.png') left center no-repeat;
  width:23px; 
  height:24px; 
  position:relative;
}
```

So the output will be

> img2 heading img1 img2

and heading text and both image are **middle/center**

but on my code above the background image not working/appear...Anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The question isn't clear to me

Comment: @koenp the background image not working/appear.

Comment: Add a height to the `H1`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `background-color` in the `background` statement. Try this:

```
.img1{
  background: transparent url('http://www.sample.com/img1.png') left center no-repeat;
  width:23px;
  height:24px;
  position:relative;
}
.img2{
  background: transparent url('http://www.sample.com/img2.png') left center no-repeat;
  width:23px; 
  height:24px; 
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: the appear become img2 <br> h1 <br> img1 <br> img2 ,,,, should img2 h1 img1 img2 => inline

Comment: Then use a <span> instead of a <div>

Comment: and now, my image was covered by text(h1), how to solve => [img2] [heading] [img1] [img2] ,,,, and 4 elements are parallel, I mean all is one line and no one located above/under